# Regex: Find all lines that contain two identical words, and delete up to the second word

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have this 2 lines:

1. `litere bebe litere oana stilou mancare acasa carte litere`
2. `litere bebe oana stilou mancare acasa carte litere`

The word `litere` is repeated 3 times in the first line, and the same word is repeated 2 times in the second line. Also, the word `stilou`is present in both lines.

So, I want to find all lines that contain two identical words (`litere`), but delete up to the second word `stilou`

Comment: In "find and delete all lines that contain two identical words (`litere`)", does "two" mean "exactly two occurrences" or "at least two occurrences"? If ` stilou` was added at the very end of the second line, should "up to the second word `stilou`" refer to the first or to the second occurrence of `stilou`?

Comment: I update my post. It is about 2 or 3  occurences of the word `litere` and one occurence of word `stilou`.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is this one:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(litere)(?=.*\1).*(stilou)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**and if I want to keep the words `litere` and `stilou`, and delete everything bewteen them, I may use this regex:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(litere)(?=.*\1).*(stilou)`
- Replace with: `\1 \2`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: The alternation `|\2` doesn't make sense, you can remove it

Comment: yes, indeed @Toto . I update my anwer, thanks